# Draw Circle at Intersection of points in highcharts heatmap

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I have a heatmap where the X and Y axis are populated dynamically.  I have used the following code to render a circle at the intersection of X and Y.  This is based off a fiddle where it was done for a scatter plot and worked in pre-5 highcharts.  Now it doesn't work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the portion of the code that is added to the sales heatmap:

```
    var circleX = 'Lukas';
    var circleY = 'Wednesday';
    var circleR = 1.0;

    function addCircle(chart){
        if (this.circle){
            $(this.circle.element).remove();
        }

        var pixelX = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(chart.xAxis[0].categories.indexOf(circleX));
        var pixelY = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(chart.yAxis[0].categories.indexOf(circleY));
        var pixelR = chart.xAxis[0].toPixles(circleR) - chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(0);
```

Here is a fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wquu41f8/)

Comment: You have typos mistakes and events configuration are placed incorrectly in the config object. After fix it, the circle is rendered. https://jsfiddle.net/wquu41f8/1/

Comment: @morganfree you are a lifesaver - thank you so very much for your help!